# Auto-completion LaTeXila doesn't work

Tags: auto-completion

After update ubuntu 16.04, auto-completion in LaTeXila has stopped working.
Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! "Stopped working” is not really helpful. Can you describe the issue in greater detail?